# java.security.NoSuchProviderException : IBMJCECCA

Tags: java, jce

This error occur while running the  following program

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

public class IBMSecureRandom1 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   try {
   // get a real random generator
    SecureRandom reallyRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("IBMSecureRandom","IBMJCECCA");
    System.out.print("Some really random numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(reallyRandom.nextInt() + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    // make a pseudo random generator seeded by the real random generator
    Random pseudoRandom = new Random(reallyRandom.nextLong());
    System.out.print("Some pseudo random numbers: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print(pseudoRandom.nextInt() + " ");
    }   
    System.out.println();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Something went wrong ...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I dont know whether i have to add any jar file or something else

Comment: Why do you want to use IBMJCECCA? Are you really using [z/OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Z/OS) and IBM JDK in the first place?

Comment: no i am not using z/OS

Comment: That do not bother with IBMJCECCA provider and `IBMSecureRandom` implementation, just use what is available in [JCE provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecureRandom).

Comment: ya, but still error is coming, do i need to add any jar file??

Comment: Please just use `new SecureRandom()` if you do not understand what strings should be specified as algorithm name and provider name.

Comment: i understand the algorithm(IBMSecureRandom) use in the code, i am prefering the book Java Security on z/OS -
The Complete View , and also download the SDK for z/OS but cant yet install it.

Answer (score 0):

From : http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/tools/java/faq/javasecurityfaq.html

You will see this error when an application issues a `Service.getInstance(algorithm,provider)`
and the specified provider is not installed in the JVM. The installation instructions provided in [How do I install the IBMJCECCA provider?](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/tools/java/faq/javasecurityfaq.html#cca_02) can be used to install any provider as long as you know the package and class name.

Comment: But first OP will need to obtain IBMJCECCA from somewhere.